# xcode programming, which folder I should put my .xib file in?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I forgot how to link my .xib file to my xcode project, been busy, forgot lots of things.
I appreciate the quick answers, that will save my jumping into apple docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.xib` files are usually put in the Resources folder, although it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: oh,here's the situation: The Project was created as a Window Based Project, and then I created a ViewController Class to the Project, write some code into viewDidLoad, and i created the .xib file. oh, by the way Felixs, thank you for your reply first, how to "grey background" the text, make it looks like code? then i created the .xib file, put it into Resources folder, check box, changed "File's Owner" class to my ViewController's name, linked view to View. and got back to the AppDelegate, link it with ViewController, but it failed, [window addSubView:viewController.view] errored, not finish

Comment: and there are still things to fix, when you created these files separately and want to glue them together. and I came out get to cross the problems, created a View Based Project instead, and things works fine, saved a lot time. Thank you Felixs! i will someday wipe out the glue process and post here, thank you overflowers!

Comment: Ok good good flutewang :). A window-based project is a bit more complicated because the basics of the app aren't yet in place; you still need to link the a new view controller etc.